# Как убрать system navigation bar в Android?

Tags: java, android, style, android-manifest, navigationbar

[image]

В `AndroidManifest.xml` добавил строчку:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Но при сборке и запуске проекта осталась панель `system navigation bar`.

Кто-нибудь может объяснить подробно, как ее убрать, желательно самым простым способом (так как в Java не силен).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галку слева от него

Answer (score 4):

Есть такой способ:

```
private fun hideSystemUI() {
    // Enables regular immersive mode.
    // For "lean back" mode, remove SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE.
    // Or for "sticky immersive," replace it with SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
            // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
            // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            // Hide the nav bar and status bar
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
}
```

Это [документация](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html#EnableFullscreen) по полному экрану. И [вот](https://github.com/android/user-interface-samples/tree/master/ImmersiveMode/) есть пример указанный в документации.

Вот этот же метод но только на java:

```
private void hideSystemUI() {
    // Enables regular immersive mode.
    // For "lean back" mode, remove SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE.
    // Or for "sticky immersive," replace it with SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
            // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
            // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            // Hide the nav bar and status bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо.Но в какое место мне приписать эту функцию?

Comment: не знаю, вам ведь нужно где-то скрывать навигацию, активность или фрагмент, вот там  используйте, вставьте функцию в активность например и дальше в методе `onCreate()` вызывайте ее